# How do I activate monetization on my YouTube channel?

Tags: youtube

I want to make money on youtube, and I heard that you have to enable it but didn't know how to. So I searched up "how to make money on youtube", and it brought up this tutorial guide: https://creatoracademy.youtube.com/page/lesson/revenue-basics#strategies-zippy-link-2

On the first step, it says: After signing into YouTube, enter YouTube Studio, and select “Monetization” from the left menu. Under “Monetization”, follow the onscreen steps to accept the YouTube Partner Program Terms.

I followed the steps listed but realized that there is no Monetization button on the left. This does not make any sense. here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhkB3.png)

Comment: Questions about YouTube are out of scope here at Super User.

Comment: then why is there a youtube tag?

Comment: You should read the description of the YouTube tag.  The reason the tag exists is that it was created by a user, given a tag description, and continued to be used and was never deleted by another user.  There are lots of tags that specifically indicate the topic is **out of scope** here at Super User.  A tag might exist, specifically to write a usage description, so the user can be pointed to the correct community.  If you disagree that a question about YouTube is out of scope, open a meta discussion, at meta.superuser.com (which is the only proper place for that dicussion).

Comment: in that case, do you know the correct site to post youtube related questions?

Comment: The correct community is specified in the tag description.  You really should read the tag description of a tag before you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube has changed its policy. In order to do monetisazion, you have to be a partner. In order to become a partner, you must have more than 1000 subscribers and a total of 4000 or more hours of watchtime.

Once your channel is eligible to become a partner, you must request to become a partner. Once you are a partner, the monitisation option should be available to you.

See also [Youtube Partner Program](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/72851?hl=en)